# Is it possible to redirect request to postman mock server to IIS express server running on local machine

Tags: postman

I have test web Api running on my local machine. What I was thinking is there is a way to send request from internet to this local web api.

Currently I send request to postman mock server for testing the remote applications behaviour. Is there is a way to redirect request to postman mock server to test Api running on local machine.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just replace the postman mock server domain with the domain or IP or your local machine?

Comment: I have private IP assign to my local machine

Comment: Where is the HTTP request sent from? The browser, or Postman?

Comment: It sent from Iot(Arduino base) device

Comment: Ah, I understand. So you have already burned the HTTP destination to postman mock server and don't want to replace it in all the IoT devices. Right?

Comment: No not like that. Right now I don't have way  to send http request directly to  local machine where the web service running(this is testing service for my school project). So I was thinking about services that can capture http request  and redirect it to may local machine. I don't know it is possible to do. Sorry if my explanation is not good.

Comment: So, you can only send HTTP request to server in internet (such as postman mock server), but cannot send it to local server with private IP? Pretty weird.